# How do you trash items on new Mac Photos?

Tags: macos, photos, trash

IPhoto had a trash bin, I need to delete images when and if I want, but I can't find the bin on the new Photos? The whole new system is freaking me out, I preferred the old.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the delete key while a photo is selected or while viewing a photo. To recover photos, a "Show Recently Deleted" option is available in the File menu. On this screen you can permanently delete a photo or recover it within 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait 30 days...

1. Select a photo
2. Press the "Delete" button
3. Confirm delete
4. Select "Album" from the top of the window (see screenshot)
5. Double click on "Recently Deleted" album to open it
6. Select "Delete All"

[image: select "album" segment from the top]

Comment: thank you
why does mac have to add such extra trouble.. we are busy enough without having to figure out all these new things that worked perfectly before..

Comment: to sell icloud accounts duh